# Update an external MYSQL database every..2mines from an internal one

Tags: linux, shell, mysql

How can I update a MYSQL database ever few minutes to an external database?

I was thinking of doing a database dump every 2 minutes to the other server, then the other server could have a cron job to apply the new data to it's database, good idea?

The reason I want to do this is because I have 2 servers, one which doesn't pretty much all the web stuff and the other which does all the heavy work, e.g. copying hudge files (sometimes a few to many that the server starts to lag).

At the moment I access the 2nd server's DB straight from the web server, but this creates a timeout sometimes when the 2nd server is over worked, so thats why I want to make a copy of the database from the 2nd server to the first (the web server), so that there wont be any more timeouts and it can get it's info from a local DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use mysqldump to export the database to a remote server. So then you would use need to put the command in a script that loops every 2 mins.

Have a look at the below link under the "Backup / Restore" section:
http://www.readylines.com/mysql-mysqladmin-mysqldump-one-liners-examples

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use mysql replication? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html